# AWS Cognito Pre-SignUp Lambda Trigger Linking Account

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have a `presign-up` cognito lambda trigger in nodejs. This trigger, links users signing in with google to existing users in cognito. So far this works in regards to linking the users, but only if I return an error in the function does it not create another user in cognito.

So right now I have

```
const run = require("./index");

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(event, null, 4));
  if (event.triggerSource !== "PreSignUp_ExternalProvider") {
    return event;
  }
  const userPoolId = event.userPoolId;
  const email = event.request.userAttributes.email;
  const username = event.userName;

  const allow = await run(userPoolId, email, username);
  if (!allow) {
    return Promise.reject("NO_USER");
  }
  return Promise.reject("MERGED_GOOGLE");
};
```

On the client when the user tries to log-in for the first time using google, the following response is sent in the url:
`/#error_description=PreSignUp+failed+with+error+MERGED_GOOGLE.+&state=Er4wfOE1grgx8lVHVl8EhIkYWIVtTo96&error=invalid_request`. Subsequently when the user tries to login again via google, this works fine and no errors are presented in the client. The user is successfully linked to the corresponding cognito user and all works. It all works apart from that first login attempt!

If I change this however to

```
const run = require("./index");

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(event, null, 4));
  if (event.triggerSource !== "PreSignUp_ExternalProvider") {
    return event;
  }
  const userPoolId = event.userPoolId;
  const email = event.request.userAttributes.email;
  const username = event.userName;

  const allow = await run(userPoolId, email, username);
  if (!allow) {
    return Promise.reject("NO_USER");
  }
  return event;
};
```

The link is created between the users, but an additional google user is added to the userpool and again in the first login attempt there is an error in the client, but this time with: `/#error_description=Already+found+an+entry+for+username+google_<googleId>+&state=gBXzf4AgMRzJ9PWWFoNfIX2tFDeNnVAg&error=invalid_request`

The question is, how do I prevent the extra user from being created in the user pool whilst linking the users and not having the error in the url in the first sign-in attempt?

I have a suspicion that this is accomplished with another lambda trigger, but which one? Or does the response from my existing trigger need to be different and how?

Comment: This is a known problem. Unfortunately you just have to handle the first error, and either tell the user to restart sign-in, or do it for them.

Comment: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=814422

Comment: have you found a way to solve this issue?